# jqplot - date axis renderer : internationalization

Tags: jquery, internationalization, jqplot

I use *jqplot*, and I have date into my x-axis.

I use the *DateAxisRenderer* plugin but I want to translate the date to my current locale.

For example, **for english**

```
Jan 2012 
Feb 2012...
```

and **for french**

```
Jan 2012
Fév 2012...
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### A bit of explanation

jqPlot uses jsDate internally: http://sandbox.kendsnyder.com/date2/

jsDate has built-in localization support and locale detection.
This capability, however, is limited to a few ,pre-configured languages, on internal regional table (see **2.**).

**1. For the lucky ones**

Since in my version of jqPlot (v1.0.4) the French language is included in this table (maybe a gift from the authors) all you have to do is simply setting the `lang` attribute on your `<html>` tag:

```
<html lang="fr">
```

Et voilà...

**2. Foreigners**

If you want to add your own missing language at runtime you can use these instructions:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // Add a new localization
    $.jsDate.regional['it'] = {
        monthNames: ['Gennaio','Febbraio','Marzo','Aprile','Maggio','Giugno','Luglio','Agosto','Settembre','Ottobre','Novembre','Dicembre'],
        monthNamesShort: ['Gen','Feb','Mar','Apr','Mag','Giu','Lug','Ago','Set','Ott','Nov','Dic'],
        dayNames: ['Domenica','Lunedi','Martedi','Mercoledi','Giovedi','Venerdi','Sabato'],
        dayNamesShort: ['Dom','Lun','Mar','Mer','Gio','Ven','Sab'],
        formatString: '%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S'
    };
    // Do not forget to call
    $.jsDate.regional.getLocale();
});
```

Do not forget to call `$.jsDate.regional.getLocale()` to refresh internal settings and to set the `<html>` tag accordingly.

Mine looks like:

```
<html lang="it">
```

That's all...

If you aren't able to control the markup for the `html` tag, you can set it with

```
document.documentElement.setAttribute('lang', 'it');
```

It doesn't work to set `lang` of an intermediate element, like a surrounding `div`.

Comment: Thank you Allessandro, it's a very good and clear answer. I added some information about setting the lang attribute with js.